# How to show timezone Dropdown at registration time in joomla?

Tags: joomla

I want to show Timezone Drop down at registration time, Joomla provide any settings show drop down either code?

Answer (score 0):

No, by default it does not. 
User can set timezone in his/her "Profile" page only after registration.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Easy Profile extension to extend the users manager.  This is probably the best of its kind.

https://www.easy-profile.com

I'm not sure if it will have a timezone selection already built in, but if not you can make custom fields and drop downs.